# When should I fertilize my fields?

Tags: farming-simulator-2015

When should I fertilize my fields on *Farming Simulator 2015*? Should I do it before or after I plant?

Answer (score 1):

It does not really matter when you fertilize, as long as you do it after cultivating and before the crops start to grow. So if you want to be on the safe side, do it before planting.